# Does an NPN Capacitive proximity sensor exist?

Tags: proximity-sensor

With proxy sensors you generally have 2 types, the NPN and PNP type sensor. I also realized that you have inductive and capacitive proxy sensors...

My problem is that I've come to understand PNP to be for the capacitive and NPN for inductive sensors.  Is this true?
Is there an NPN capacitive proxy sensor and how does it work?

Comment: With industrial sensors, NPN vs PNP just refers to the type of output the sensor has and has no direct link to what the sensor senses or the method of sensing.

Answer (score 1):

As brhans pointed in the comment NPN and PNP refers only to the output see here an example of NPN and PNP outputs:

[image: NPN output]

[image: PNP output]

See an example of [capacitive proximity sensor from Omron](http://www.ia.omron.com/data_pdf/cat/e2k-x_ds_e_8_1_csm460.pdf?id=471) that can be ordered either in PNP or NPN version.